# PHP Script to MD5 Hash Each Line Separately

Tags: php, md5

I'm trying to create a script that can MD5 hash many lines (50,000+) quickly. I have a script I've been trying to make work, but it gives me different outputs sometimes and I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

```
  <?php  
     if(isset($_POST['btn'])){
            $value=$_POST['text'];
            $ids = explode(PHP_EOL, $value);
            $content = '';
            for ($i=0;$i<count($ids);$i++){
                $content .= md5($ids[$i]).'<br>';
            }

            echo nl2br($content);
     }
     ?>
```

When I try to hash:

```
apples  
bananas  
oranges  
pineapples
```

It results in:

```
265f78fc274d8428fd63dabc24400cb4  
63a63ddf49984e0f1cef336aeb6ca39c  
229b1cc78a248c6cea47fa95565dc9ca  
019b111ec0c13ed923922715bfb1670a
```

But I should be getting:

```
daeccf0ad3c1fc8c8015205c332f5b42  
ec121ff80513ae58ed478d5c5787075b  
91b07b3169d8a7cb6de940142187c8df  
019b111ec0c13ed923922715bfb1670a
```

Comment: Why are you using `nl2br()` when you put explicit `<br>` in `$content`?

Comment: you've got some spaces after your words. I get correct results after removing the spaces here: https://3v4l.org/njDvi

Comment: @Jeff CR, not spaces

Comment: @Barmar I had spaces when I copy&pasted the OP's code. Didn't see the CR... Maybe 3v4l.org made \n out of the CR automatically and/or their server is configuered differently. Anyway, your trim seems to be the best answer anyway (as always)

Comment: There are no CR in the SO question, the CR->space translation probably happened when he was pasting here.

Comment: @Jeff In any case, the `trim()` solution will solve it either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines in your input string are separated by `\r\n`, but on your server `PHP_EOL` is set to `\n`. So when you split the input into lines, there's a `\r` at the end of each line except the last. `echo md5("apples\r");` produces `265f78fc274d8428fd63dabc24400cb4`.

Use `trim()` to remove extra whitespace.

```
$content .= md5(trim($ids[$i])).'<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have whitespaces in your input data. And don't collect all 50k+ hashes in memory.
Try this

```
<?php  
if(isset($_POST['btn'])){
    $value=$_POST['text'];
    $ids = explode(PHP_EOL, $value);
    for ($i=0;$i<count($ids);$i++){
        echo nl2br(md5(trim($ids[$i])));
    }
}
?>
```